# Domain works perfect external, issues when using safari internal

Tags: ubuntu, domain, reverse-proxy

I'm currently working on a server which holds a few applications like Jenkins and sonartube for example.

I've created a reverse proxy for those applications. let's say the addresses are Jenkins.example.com and sonar.example.com. They are linked to an actual subdomain which is pointed to my external IP address.

I have a PFSense router on which I forwarded the ports 80 and 443 to the proxy server.

When I try to access Jenkins.example.com from outside of my external network it works perfectly fine without any problems.

When I try to reach the domain from the internal network issues arise. the page will load in the beginning but after clicking around a few times it will stop working and the page won't load anymore. If I switch to the dedicated ip's internally it works perfectly fine. After some testing it appears that it does work fine on chrome but it doesn't work on safari.

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this or how I can even begin to debug this. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

I'm using apache2 for my proxyserver.

The strange thing is that I have another server at a different location with the exact same setup and there it all works perfectly fine.

Comment: - Are your browsers using a proxy server? If so, are exceptions correctly configured?

Comment: Also, to what IP address do jenkins.example.com and sonar.example.com resolve from the internal network?